# Is it possible to create/manage bots in Nextcloud Talk like in Telegram

Tags: nextcloud

I have read all documentation on https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/developer_manual, but not found any information about Bot creation like in Telegram https://core.telegram.org/bots. Googling this question got me no relevant results.
Has anybody experience in this question?

Answer (score 0):

I was asking me the same question and found [this issue](https://github.com/nextcloud/spreed/issues/1936). As a result I created the needed api myself. You'll find it on [github](https://github.com/boppy/nextcloud-talk-bot) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextcloud-talk-bot).

*Where is the **ad** button? ;)*